# Meshlab 2020.03 Pick point icon

Tags: meshlab

I downloaded Meshlab 2020.03, however the Pick Points icon on the taskbar is not there so I am not able to collect 3D landmark coordinate data, how do I find it with this new version or is there a way to add it(plug in)on?

I have looked at two answers of the same question; however, they were not answered correctly.

N

Answer (score 1):

It has been reintroduced on Meshlab 2020.06